# How to identify the underlying data structure in Redis after "GET"ting them?

Tags: redis

I am using an API to fetch all kinds of data from Redis and perform different operations on them. In case of bitmaps and HLLs, I am not able to do this since they are both stored as strings on and running get on keys belonging to these data structures I am not able to differentiate between the returned values whether they are from normal string keys or HLLs or bitmaps.

Is there a redis command to identify the underlying data structure to which data structure the returned value belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

No, for bitmaps and HLLs there's no way to get that information, because redis does not store it. Any given string could conceivably be just some string, or a bitmap. Every string is also a valid bitmap, and every bitmap can be interpreted as a string.

Of course you could hack together some heuristics, but those are bound to fail, and obviously terribly ugly.

If you have any control over the data definition, you can encode such information in the KEY.

(Previous, uninformed answer follows)

Yes, there's the [`TYPE` command](https://redis.io/commands/type):

```
redis> SET key1 "value"
"OK"
redis> LPUSH key2 "value"
(integer) 1
redis> SADD key3 "value"
(integer) 1
redis> TYPE key1
"string"
redis> TYPE key2
"list"
redis> TYPE key3
"set"
```

Comment: But bitmaps and HLLs are both stored as strings so I am not able to differentiate them from normal strings. Let's say I have retrieved a value using GET can I find the underlying data structure?

Comment: Its okay @MattW. please post a solution if you can find one.

Comment: Actually, despite being encoded as string, HLLs always start with the prefix "HYLL". This allows us to have false positives but never false negatives when checking whether the value is an actual HLL or not. Bitmaps and bitfields - no way to identify as answered, you have to have a priori knowledge.